# Identify this ciphered number

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

I have enciphered a particular number. Decode and identify this number:

> 200400100500300300100900500800100200500400300100200000600500300400400

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  I'm glad you're eager to contribute a puzzle here, but I fear this one is not going to fare well. You may want to read [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/30633) for some guidance on how to approach cipher puzzles in general (though this hardly counts as a cipher; see e.g. [Guide to Codes and Ciphers](/q/52118/30633) for info on what's usually considered a "cipher").

Comment: Beyond that, "identify this number" for something trivially found on OEIS isn't much of a puzzle either (relevant: [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712/30633)). You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out the high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of what kinds of puzzles work best here.  Welcome again, and hope your next puzzle sees great success!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the cipher is:

> Inserting two 0's after each digit in the number

which when deciphered gives:

> 24153319581254312065344

Huh?

> It's the first 6-way taxicab number - i.e. the first number that can be expressed as the sum of 2 cubes in 6 distinct ways
>
>
>  $24153319581254312065344 =\\ 28906206^3 + 582162^3 = 28894803^3 + 3064173^3 = 28657487^3 + 8519281^3 =\\ 27093208^3 + 16218068^3 = 26590452^3 + 17492496^3 = 26224366^3 + 18289922^3$

Note:

> I don't think this is a particularly interesting cipher.

Comment: It looks more like adding two zeros after each digit to me